# How to upgrade or flash IOS on Cisco 4503E without flash?

Tags: cisco, cisco-ios, cisco-catalyst

I am trying to restore Cisco catalyst 4503E switch. When I turn on it I enter rommon mode? How to restore or fix this problem ? Unfortunately, I haven't a flash card. 
Here is my screeenshots:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick google search finds this:
[Recover a Cisco IOS Catalyst 4500/4000 Series Switch from a Corrupt or Missing Image or in Rommon Mode](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/switches/catalyst-4000-series-switches/24061-149.html)

To summarise:

1) First check if there is an image present in the (built-in) bootflash:

```
rommon >dir bootflash:
```

If there is, then try to boot it like this (obviously, replacing "cat4000-is-mz.121-11b.EW" with the name of the image you found using the "dir" command above):

```
rommon >boot bootflash:cat4000-is-mz.121-11b.EW
```

2) If there is no image on the bootflash or it doesn't boot, then you will need to connect the management port of the SUP to a TFTP server, put a valid image on the TFTP server and use this procedure to boot from TFTP (and again, replace the ip addresses and image name to suit your setup of course):

```
 rommon >unset boot
 rommon >set interface fa1 14.18.2.234 255.255.255.0
 rommon >set ip route default 14.18.2.21
 rommon >boot tftp://172.18.125.3/cat4000-is-mz.121-11b.EW
```